# Is there a bug about using RDD.cartesian with Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

My code :

```
ks1 = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum='localhost:2181', groupId='G1', topics={'test': 2})
ks2 = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum='localhost:2181', groupId='G2', topics={'test': 2})

d1 = ks1.map(lambda x: x[1]).flatMap(lambda x: list(x)).countByValue()
d2 = ks2.map(lambda x: x[1]).flatMap(lambda x: list(x)).countByValue()

d3 = d1.transformWith(lambda t, x, y: x.cartesian(y), d2)
```

And then I get some error :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD
>   cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD

p.s. Python2.7.11 + Spark 2.0.2

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a known bug. Here is a JIRA:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17756